# problema de razonamiento lógico java

Tags: java

tengo un fallo en mi proceso lógico, pide que dado 3 valores determine cual es numero mayor teniendo en cuenta que se pueden repetir los números...
pero a la hora de ejecutarlo y dando 3 valores iguales me sale el mensaje de "EL primer y segundo numero son mayores".
Quisiera saber si me podrían ayudar... Gracias de antemano

```
if ((num1 >= num2) && (num1 >= num3))
        {
            if (num1 == num2)
            {
                System.out.println("El primer y segundo numero son mayores.");
            }
            else if (num1 == num3)
            {
                System.out.println("El primer y tercer numero son mayores.");
            }
            else 
            {
            System.out.println("El Primer numero es mayor.");
            }
        }
        else if ((num2 >= num1) && (num2 >= num3))
        {
            if (num2 == num3)
            {
                System.out.println("El segundo y tercer numero son mayores");
            }
            else 
            {
            System.out.println("El segundo numero es mayor.");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("El tercer numero es mayor.");
        }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes del 1º If añades un if que tenga 2 condiciones que comprueben si el num1 y el num2 sean iguales y que el num2 y el num3 sean iguales. Si alguno de ellos es diferente procede al siguiente if

```
if ((num1 >= num2) && (num1 >= num3))
        {
            if ((num1 == num2) && (num1==num3))
            {
                System.out.println("Toos los numeros son iguales.");
            }
            else if (num1 == num2)
            {
                System.out.println("El primer y segundo numero son mayores.");
            }
            else if (num1 == num3)
            {
                System.out.println("El primer y tercer numero son mayores.");
            }
            else 
            {
            System.out.println("El Primer numero es mayor.");
            }
        }
        else if ((num2 >= num1) && (num2 >= num3))
        {
            if (num2 == num3)
            {
                System.out.println("El segundo y tercer numero son mayores");
            }
            else 
            {
            System.out.println("El segundo numero es mayor.");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("El tercer numero es mayor.");
        }

        }
```

Comment: muchas gracias, funciono¡¡¡¡